# Deleting the gray header in blazor default template

Tags: blazor, .net-7.0

In Blazor (.net 7), how do you delete the gray header in the body that has the About link in the default template?

Answer (score 0):

In `MainLayout.razor` you delete:

```html
<div class="top-row px-4">
    <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
</div>
```